# Editing Non-G/L custom Transaction Fields in Assembly Build "View"

Tags: netsuite

I'm looking to try and see if there is a way to enable a Non-G/L "check box" custom field to be able to be checked or unchecked from the 'View' status of a G/L Posting Transaction (Item Receipt or Assembly Build, etc.). The purpose of the field is to be able to be used for audit error tracking and would like to see if it can be edited in such a way, and then by such logic, allow for those fields to be edited on Closed periods where "*Allow Non-G/L Changes*" has been checked on.

Can't seem to find any such options on the "Custom Record" field or the "Custom Transaction Form", so wondering if anyone knows if there's a specific permission or option that needs to be set aside from the "*Allow Non-G/L Changes*". Thanks!

[Example Transaction Check Box Fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Wuy5.png)

TLDR: *Allow Non-G/L Changes* is enabled in the closed period of my transaction; however, since I am unable to "edit" this transaction, I cannot check the non-G/L impacting custom field Checkbox that is on those transactions, and need to figure out if there is a way to edit fields without being in "edit mode".

Comment: Update: I was able to accomplish at least what I needed which was editing a non-G/L impacting change on closed-period transactions. The issue was the role I was testing with had the "Allow Non-G/L Changes" permission set to "None". Once, that permission was enabled, I was able to see the "edit" button, and update the checkbox cells in the closed transactions. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to (from view context) be able to update the values of those 3 checkboxes. Correct?

There might be a better way to do this, but you can add buttons to the record using a UserEvent script that call a ClientScript similar to this.

```js
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
*/
define([], function () {
  function beforeLoad(context) {
    // make sure not to add the button in create or edit context
    if (context.type !== context.UserEventType.VIEW) return;
    context.form.clientScriptModulePath = "SuiteScripts/Path/To/Your/Script.js";
    context.form.addButton({
      id: "custpage_button",
      label: "My Label",
      functionName: "checkBox.call(this)",
    });
  }
  return {beforeLoad: beforeLoad};
});
```

```js
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
*/
define(["N/currentRecord", "N/record"], function (currentRecord, record) {
  // this function should be named whatever you are defining in your user event script as the "functionName" when adding the button
  function checkBox() {
    var curr = currentRecord.get();
    // check the checkbox
    record.submitFields({
      id: curr.id,
      type: curr.type,
      columns: {
        custbody_mycheckbox: "T",
      },
    });
    // reload the page to present the most up to date information
    window.location.reload();
  }
  return {
    pageInit: function () {},
    checkBox: checkBox,
  }
});
```